# Store text: array vs constant to best performance

Tags: php, arrays, constants

I'm coding a multi language website. The text for each page is loaded from a MySQL database and should be assigned to an array or constant to insert it into the web content.

I would like to know if it is better, to save memory and for best performance, the use of constants or arrays to store the text. i.e.

```
foreach ($db_text_object as $t){
  $text["$t->key"] = $t->text;
}
```

or:

```
foreach ($db_text_object as $t){
  define($t->key, $t->text);
}
```

To be used as:

```
echo $text['mytext'];
```

or:

```
echo mytext;
```

Any other comment about advantage or disadvantage of each method will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not benchmark both and see? You can run `php` from the command line so you do not have to manually reload the website multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference will be too *trivial* or *too minute*

I personally go with the arrays, since you would be able to access it in a simpler way..

#### Benchmarking results...

```
<?php


$db_text_object=[1,2,3,4,5];
$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($db_text_object as $k=>$v){
    $text[$k] = $v;
}
echo "Constant Performance: " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($db_text_object as $k=>$v){
    define($k, $v);
}
echo "Array Performance: " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "\n";
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
Constant Performance: 1.9073486328125E-5 
Array Performance: 1.3113021850586E-5
```

[<kbd>Benchmarking Demo at CodeViper</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q058cI)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either will have a significant impact on performance, especially since the bottleneck will be getting all the data from the database every single time. If you're really interested in whether it makes a difference: try it both ways and measure it.

When you're done doing that, do it right by using a native extension like [gettext](http://php.net/gettext), which was made for this exact purpose, does internal caching of binary translation files and comes with a whole ecosystem of tools supporting the translation workflow.

Comment: Thank you for the advise, but gettext is not a valid solution for my current project. Finaly I'v used arrays.